# A way to read off $\deg \phi(P)$ directly from $P$ where $\phi:\mathbb{C}[x_1, \cdots, x_n]^{\mathfrak{S}_n}\to \mathbb{C}[e_1, \cdots, e_n]$?

Tags: symmetric-polynomials

Let $P(x_1, \cdots, x_n)\in \mathbb{C}[x_1, \cdots, x_n]^{\mathfrak{S}_n}$ be a symmetric polynomial and $Q(e_1, \cdots, e_n)$ be its image under the isomorphism $\mathbb{C}[x_1, \cdots, x_n]^{\mathfrak{S}_n}\to \mathbb{C}[e_1, \cdots, e_n]$ where $e_i$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials. Suppose we know that $Q(e_1, \cdots, e_n)$ is of degree $d$. My question is

> Is there a way one can read off $d$ directly from $P$?More directly I'm wondering if there is a differential operator $D$ in $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ such
>   that $DP=dP$?

Comment: the degree of $Q$ is the degree of $P$ as a polynomial in $x_1$ (or any other variable)

Comment: @mercio Can you elaborate? Presumably the OP doesn't yet see that.

Comment: Of course you're right! Local degree... Was thinking too complicated...